# screen session loses contact to AFS file system

Tags: filesystems, gnu-screen, afs

Our $HOME file system is an openAFS system.  I log on to my desktop machine from my laptop at home and want to run a long job.  Thus to protect it from a broken session, I open up

```
screen -S session_name
```

and run the script from there, and then disconnect the screen session.  My problem is that after a relatively short time of a few hours, the session loses contact to the AFS file system, so I can't use any files there in the script stored on my $HOME.  If I reconnect later to the session I can't list any files there or change directory to my home, I simply get a permission denied error.

I tried the following commands to try and reconnect, which usually work if I have left my desktop logged in too long:

```
fs checkservers
fs checkvolumes
fs flush
```

but that doesn't help the screen session to reconnect.  Does anyone know how I can keep access to AFS in a disconnected screen session, or place a command in my bash/python scripts to keep it alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest running `krenew`, which has the option to run a command with the -t flag, which by default is `aklog`. It’s usually packaged as part of the [kstart](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/) package.

Run the `krenew` inside the screen session. Make sure you get [renewable](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/user/tkt_mgmt.html) Kerberos tickets, and your institutions KDC might have limits on how long your ticket can be renewed. As long as the Kerberos ticket is valid, krenew will run aklog and get updated tokens.

If you want to keep the ticket for a long while, make sure that the credential cache is the same every time you log in (for example, use the KEYRING), that way every time you ssh in, the krenew process will have access to the refreshed tgt. You set the default ccache name in /etc/krb5.conf.

I basically do this with tmux, and I also use the [kAFS](https://www.infradead.org/~dhowells/kafs/) client as well as OpenAFS for home directories.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, I'm getting an error: error reading ticket cache: No credentials cache found (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_8619_llISU1), do I need to use kinit first when I first open the screen session?

Comment: Yes, `krenew` only works with an existing Kerberos ticket.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a solution that was suggested to me to try today.

First Login to the computer in question via ssh

Then run the following command  to create a new kerberos/AFS session.

```
pagsh
```

Run the following to authenticate again with AFS

```
klog
```

Use the following command to verify that you have a token

```
tokens
```

Run screen with the -l option to force a login shell

```
screen -l -S session_name
```

Start your application and disconnect... So far it seems to work.